# Azure Devops Releases - Automatically Queue Release From Build Based on Variable

Tags: azure-devops

I have a setup where anyone can create artifacts from any branch of our code base from a pipeline in pipelines -> pipelines then use that artifact to create a release in pipelines -> releases. I want to enable the user to be able to set a variable in the build pipeline that creates the artifact and have that automatically trigger a release once the build finishes. Is this possible and how would I do it?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 1):

We cannot set the variable in the build pipeline to create the artifacts and automatically trigger a release once the build finishes

As a workaround, We can configure the [Release triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops) to automatically trigger the release after the build is complete.

Steps:

1. Create a new release pipeline->select the build as source type->enable the feature
2. Continuous deployment trigger and configure it.